# Is there a way to make items in a div be spaced by a specific amount?

Tags: html, css

This seems quite simple, but I'm not sure how to approach this.
I have 4 links in a header and a logo to the left. I have another div that all these links are in called main-header-right. Is there a way without adding classes to all of the links, to space these links out a bit?

```css
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 1% 0%;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.main-header-right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"><b>Fallen</b></a>
        <div class="main-header-right">
            <a href="#">About Me</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Prices</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a child selector like `.main-header-right a`.

```css
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 1% 0%;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.main-header-right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main-header-right a{
    padding: 0 20px;

}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"><b>Fallen</b></a>
        <div class="main-header-right">
            <a href="#">About Me</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Prices</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I used `padding`. The other answers that came in while I wrote my answer use `margin`. The difference is that `padding` also makes the "clickable" part of the link bigger, `margin` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it by applying the style to all child anchors of .main-header-right

```
.main-header-right > a{
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Below is the Working code:

```css
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 1% 0%;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.main-header-right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main-header-right > a{
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"><b>Fallen</b></a>
            <div class="main-header-right">
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">Prices</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

To know more about CSS Combinatiors:
[W3Schools Css Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Answer (score 1):

by adding margin-left for ex

```
.main-header-right a {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```css
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 1% 0%;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.main-header-right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main-header-right a {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"><b>Fallen</b></a>
            <div class="main-header-right">
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">Prices</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
    </div>
```